# ActiveRecord: find appropriate translation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have models:
`Category`:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :entities, as: :resourcable

end

class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :categories do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :short_descr
      t.text :full_descr

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

`Language`:

```
class Language < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :entities, as: :resourcable, dependent: :destroy

  validates :code, uniqueness: true

end

class CreateLanguages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :languages do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :code

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

And `Entity`:

```
class Entity < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :language
  belongs_to :resourcable, polymorphic: true

end

class CreateEntities < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :entities do |t|
      t.integer :language_id
      t.string :name
      t.text :short_descr
      t.text :full_descr
      t.references :resourcable, polymorphic: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

In `Categories` there are default values for fields (`short_descr`, `full_descr`), In `Entities` there are translations for this fields. I need to render as `json` all `Categories` with appropriate translations: at first, I need to take `Language` with appropriate `code` (for example `ru`), next, I need to find all language `Entities` for this language, next, if `Entity` have filled `short_descr` and `full_descr` I need to render `Category` with this values, else I need to render the `Category` with default values (this values in `Categories` table). How to do this? I prefer ActiveRecord buy consider pure SQL.

**EDITED**
Now I'm trying to use `gem 'squeel'`:

```
Language.joins{entities.category}.
        select{coalesce(entities.short_descr, categories.short_descr)}.
        where{languages.code == 'en'}
```

but it doesn't work (`undefined method`short_descr' for nil:NilClass`). There is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
Entity.joins(:language, :category).
        select('categories.*, coalesce(entities.short_descr, categories.short_descr) as short_descr,
            coalesce(entities.full_descr, categories.full_descr) as full_descr').
        where('languages.code = ?', 'en')
```